# How do I manage SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Add-In?

Tags: ssms

A variety of vendors provide [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Add-Ins](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-management-studio-add-ins), such as [Red Gate's SQL Prompt](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) and the [SSMS Tools Pack](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).

Is there a way in SSMS to control or configure these add-ins (enable/disable, install/uninstall)?

Is there an add-in or plug-in manager?

If not, is there another way to review and control them?

An [old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676827/re-enable-ssms-addin) references [some registry keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17718983/2266979), but they appear to be relevant only to a 2008 version of SSMS. They aren't present on my system. Another answer references [some folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678242/2266979), but only one of them exists on my system (ProgramData\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins) and it has only one of several installed add-ins ([Sentry One Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer)).

Other keywords: addin manager, addon manager, add-on manager, plugin manager, plug-in manager, extension manager

Comment: Fun fact: SSMS doesn't _technically_ support add-ins... (So no fancy management UIs.) I'm not sure if there's a secret handshake you can do in the registry, but nothing "official"